# PHP unexpected T_BOOLEAN_AND error?

Tags: php, html, css

Can you please help me? now i'm looking into this code for about 8 hours and i just can't seem to get it working, now it says unexpected boolean here:

```
if (isset($_POST['nick']) && isset($_POST['heslo'])) && if(isset($_POST['email'] && isset($_POST['datnar'])))
{   
    try {
        $email = ($_POST['email']);
        $datnar = ($_POST['datnar']);        
        $nick = $db->quote($_POST['nick']);
        $heslo = md5($_POST['heslo']);
        $db->query("INSERT INTO tbluser(`nick`, `heslo`, `email`, `datnar`) VALUES ($nick, '$heslo', $email, $datnar)");
        echo "Registrace dokončena.";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Uživatel existuje";
    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to combine multiple `if` statements with `and`; not simply conditions in an `if` statement

Answer (score 3):

```
if (isset($_POST['nick']) && isset($_POST['heslo']) && 
    isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['datnar']))
    {
```